# cannot reshape array of size 23715 into shape (224,224,3)

Tags: python, numpy

i am doing a skin cancer detection algorithm. The problem is that i have 2635 RGB images of 224 by 224 pixels. After data augmentation i get 23715 images (train_data).

My problem is that i get this error --> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 23715 into shape (224,224,3)

This is my code:

```
X = np.array([i[0] for i in train_data]).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
Y = [i[1] for i in train_data]

test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test_data]).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
test_y = [i[1] for i in test_data]

model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=10, shuffle=True, validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}),  
snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)
```

What should i do to fix this issue? Looking in the internet i have found similar errors but i still have problems to fix it.

Comment: Can you show the structure of `train_data`?

Comment: training_data.append([np.array(img), np.array(label)])

Comment: And what is the shape of each `img`?

Comment: the shape of each image is --> (224, 224, 3)

Comment: Add the output of `print(len(train_data), [i[0].shape for i in train_data[:5]], train_data[:5])` to your post, please. Something doesn't add up here.

Comment: 23715 [(160, 160, 3), (224, 224, 3), (224, 224, 3), (160, 160, 3), (224, 224, 3)] [[array([[[208, 189, 191],
        [206, 187, 189],
        [206, 188, 188],
      
       ...,

       [[204, 189, 192],
        [206, 190, 193],
        [208, 187, 192],
        ...,
        [199, 184, 189],
        [199, 184, 189],
        [199, 184, 189]]], dtype=uint8), array([1, 0])], [array([[[183, 115, 114],
        [192, 122, 124],
        [194, 124, 126],
      
       ...,

Comment: sorry but i cant write all the output in the comment section. Is too long.

Comment: Edit it into your post

Comment: i tried to summarize it

Comment: Edit your question and add the output at the bottom, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the images in `train_data` don't all have the same size. From your test output:

```py
>>> [i[0].shape for i in train_data[:5]]
[(160, 160, 3), (224, 224, 3), (224, 224, 3), (160, 160, 3), (224, 224, 3)]
```

There are at least two different sizes here (160x160 RGB and 224x224 RGB).

The effect is that NumPy doesn't know how to align the data when creating `X`, as the input elements don't have uniform size. If you print `X`, you'll see something like this:

```py
>>> X
array([array([[[...
    ...
    ...]]])], dtype=object)
```

which is what NumPy falls back to in cases like this.

You're going to want to track down why your images have differing sizes in your case.